# How to select directories in bash from sql table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a directory containing more than 1100 directories, i want to move about 400 directories which name i have stored in a sql table? Is there a way to achieve this? I have searched on google but i can't find anything. Maybe one possiblity should be to export the table records to a text file but i still don't know how to connect the text file to the directories. Thanks.

Comment: Add an example of your exported text file to your question.

Comment: i am trying to upload a file but i don't know how.
The content of text file is just a list with directory names:
directory1
directory2
directory3

Comment: @papacico Do you want to move the 400 directories to a single target directory, or will the directories be moved to different locations?

Comment: to a single target directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRLIST='file'
SOURCE='/my/source/directory'
TARGET='/my/target/directory'

while read -r dir; do
    echo mv "$SOURCE/$dir" "$TARGET"
done < "$DIRLIST"
```

where `file` contains

```
directory1
directory2
directory3
```

(customize the example to your specific taste, and remove the `echo` statement in front of the `mv` after testing)

Comment: @papacico No, my roots are near Stoccarda, Italy's northernmost city 

Comment: ok, one more question, don't i have do specify the directory source path in your script?

Comment: @papacico Correct, and there are also two variables `SOURCE` and `TARGET` which you can change as necessary. In case your mysql text file already contains the full paths of the directories (i.e. /path/xxy/directory1 instead of just directory1), you can set SOURCE to "".

Comment: the list file only contains direcory names not path
i have set the list file in the same directory where the directories are that has to be moved but i get this error:

mv: cannot stat 'Acasamia': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Adriano': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'AdrianaAlleghe': No such file or directory

Comment: it is done i have moved also the script to the right directory and it is done, thank a lot

Comment: hi @Guido if you are interested i have posted another question txs: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527570/how-to-rename-400-directories-in-bash-using-new-directory-name-stored-in-sql-tab