# How to rename 400 directories in bash using new directory name stored in sql table

Tags: bash

i have 400 directories which i wish to rename from old name to new name, i have both old name and new name in a sql table.

The old names are like this:

- directory1
- directory2
- directory3

The new names will be like this as they will be a title of a pictures album which will be seen by a site visitors:

- The directory 1
- The directory 2
- The directory 3

I plan to export all new and old names to a text file.
I can make a 'source' file with old names and a 'target' file with new names,
or i can make one file with old and new names comma separated.
As my bash scripting knowledge is very poor i don't know how to achieve this
Thank you

Old names example

```
directory1
directory2
directory3
directory4
directory5
directory6
directory7
directory8
directory9
directory10
directory11
directory12
```

New names example

```
'The directory 1'
'The directory 2'
'The directory 3'
'The directory 4'
'The directory 5'
'The directory 6'
'The directory 7'
'The directory 8'
'The directory 9'
'The directory 11'
'The directory 11'
'The directory 12'
```

Comment: Add an example of your exported text files to your question.

Comment: How do i upload i file? @Cyrus as i never did before

Comment: the text files will just contain a vertical list of names, as the new names contains spaces i think is better if they will be between quotes like this 'The directory 1'

Comment: Add the content as example line to your question.

Comment: don't upload, just copy/paste 5-10 lines from the exported file into your question (use edit button)

Comment: Do you know that in most webserver environments you can programmatically control what directory names the users can see regardless of the actual directory names?

Comment: if i were you, i would export the file with the `mv` command, renamge the exported file to `.sh` and run it using `sh exportedFileName.sh` each line of the exported file should look like this : `mv oldDirName newDirName` pay attention to full path if needed, or just `cd` to target main dir (if all directories are in one path) and execute the file

Comment: See: [Reading lines from two files in one while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9885338/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, with SQL, you can extract a file with old and new directory names with the following format:

```
% cat extractfile
mv 'directory1' 'The Directory 1'
mv 'directory2' 'The Directory 2'
mv 'directory3' 'The Directory 3'
```

Then all you need to do is to execute that file:

```
% bash extractfile
```

Comment: If the destination file name might contain a single quote, you need to embellish this slightly. You might want to replace each literal single quote with `'"'"'` (sic).

Comment: txs a lot @mouviciel it is done this is the right solution for me